# MySQL stored procedure ignores DELETE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have this stored procedure which gets called from PHP Script. It has few select statement and a delete statement. Everything works fine apart from DELETE query does not get executed. It gets ignored !! Please help. Thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_name`(IN id INT, IN type CHAR(50))
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT 'procedure'
BEGIN 
DECLARE LEGACY_EN_ID INT;
SET IN_ID = id;
SELECT  IF(e.legacy_id > 0, e.legacy_id, 0) INTO LEGACY_EN_ID FROM tablename e WHERE e.id = IN_ID LIMIT 1;

/* Delete record if it exists */
        DELETE
        FROM tablename
        WHERE entityID = LEGACY_EN_ID;
```

Comment: Generate some SQL Fiddle example, produce the error and post it with your query.

Comment: Ignored or where condition results in no records being relevent

Comment: @Randy no commits anywhere.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson if I hard code id in the delete query, it works but i did check that LEGACY_EN_ID has a value as when I print SELECT LEGACY_EN_ID in stored procedure it does show me an id...

Comment: Bit of a guess just noticed you are using CHAR(50) instead of VarChar(50)...

Comment: tried everything but no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Check user who executes stored procedure have permission to do that.
2. This can be checked by directing connecting through mysql command line with same user and try to execute query which generated in stored procedure.
3. Or create a simple PHP script and call directly delete sql using mysql_query. If this success then you have access.

Comment: tried. permission looks fine... still no joy with the delete statement